# How do I pass a blank proxy username/password using curl?

Tags: bash, curl, proxy, passwords, tor

I’m using bash shell on Mac El Capitan.  How do I pass a blank username/password for a proxy server using curl?  I tried this

```
localhost:tmp davea$ curl http://www.google.com --proxy localhost:9050 --proxy-user "":""
514 Authentication required.
```

I’m running a tor daemon on my machine using this command

```
tor --CookieAuthentication 0 --HashedControlPassword "" --ControlPort 9050 --SocksPort 50001
```

and I’m able to connect through Telnet without entering a password like so

```
localhost:tmp davea$ telnet localhost 9050
Trying ::1...
telnet: connect to address ::1: Connection refused
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
AUTHENTICATE
250 OK
```

so I know that my password, at least, is correct.

Comment: Why are you not connecting to the socks port directly? `curl -vvvv http://www.google.com --socks5 localhost:50001 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that when using `curl` from the command line, the `--proxy` option is specifically for use with an HTTP proxy which Tor is not, it's a SOCKS proxy.

To get around this, use what Nehal suggested in the comments to use a SOCKS proxy (you'll probably want to use `--socks5-hostname` instead so the DNS resolution is also performed over Tor as well, otherwise you leak DNS requests locally).

So your call would look like:

```
curl http://www.google.com -L --socks5-hostname localhost:50001
```

Side note: The control port (9050) is only used for communicating commands to the controller.  This port is not used to proxy requests at all.